# How to get top view controller when UIImagePickerController is presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

At some time I present `UIImagePickerViewController`. Once it is presented, I call my function: `UIStoryboard.topViewController()`:

```
extension UIStoryboard {

    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let svc = base as? UISplitViewController where svc.viewControllers.count == 1 {
            return topViewController(svc.viewControllers[0])
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presented)
        }

        return base
    }
}
```

When I print result, all I get is:

> 0x000000014cb2aa00
>    {
>     UIKit.UIResponder = {...}
>   }

**How to get `UIImagePickerController` from `topViewController()` function?**

Comment: You're not supposed to mess with `UIImagePickerController`'s view hierarchy, and pushing another view controller on its stack would do that. Also, since it's a subclass of `UINavigationController`, your `topViewController` method won't even return the `UIImagePickerController`; at best it'll return the top VC on the `UIImagePickerController`'s stack.

Comment: oh, you are right, completely right.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. You're wondering how to get the image picker as the result of the topViewController function?

Comment: @Carlos yes, exactly. Return in `topViewController` a whole `UIImagePickerController`. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I have some similar code in a project I'm working on. It doesn't use UIStoryboard though. I'll paste a snippet and you can see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to your case, but here's how I find the top VC in my program. You should be able to edit it for your case.

```
class UIHelper {
static func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var currentViewController: UIViewController?
    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window {
        currentViewController = window!.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
    }
    if currentViewController == nil {
        return nil
    }

//Check for my version of my main tab bar VC
    if let tabBarController = currentViewController as? RootTabBarController {
        currentViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
        print("Tab bar presents \(currentViewController)")
    }
// Check if it's a nav VC
    if let navController = currentViewController as? UINavigationController {
        currentViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as? UIViewController
        print("Nav controller presents \(currentViewController)")
    }

    print("Current controller: \(currentViewController)")

    return currentViewController
}
}
```

Comment: No, it is not helpful:( because it still doesnt care about `UIImagePickerController`:-(

Comment: So you add a section where it checks for that class?